# How to generate Curve 25519 key pair with ECDH swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ecdh, apple-cryptokit, curve-25519

I want to generate a **Curve25519 key pair with ECDH** for the encryption and decryption. I'm using the CryptoKit to generates a keypair.

But, I failed to generate a keypair with the ECDH algorithm.

**Swift**

```
func generateKeys() -> (publicKey: String, privateKey: String){
           let privateKey = Curve25519.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
           let publicKey = privateKey.publicKey
           let clientPublicKeyString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\(publicKey.rawRepresentation.base64EncodedString())-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
           print(clientPublicKeyString)
           let clientPrivateKeyString = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\(privateKey.rawRepresentation.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"
           print(clientPrivateKeyString)
        return (clientPublicKeyString,clientPrivateKeyString)
    }
```

**Output:**

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----WSOOXYN/FaCOn4SAlvrW3q4IYueiS8Io+WqL64T2QQA=-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----AAlH4v1vcnmjEKVJrhbarMqCrcNWYZgFwnhReduEokk=-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here is one of the Java code using bouncycastle

**output of java code:**

```
{
  "privateKey": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "errorInfo": null,
  "KeyMaterials": {
    "cryptoAlg": "ECDH",
    "curve": "curve25519",
    "params": "",
    "DHPublicKey": {
      "expiry": "2020-10-15T11:29:20.848Z",
      "Parameter": "",
      "KeyValue": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBMTCB6gYHKoZIzj0CATCB3gIBATArBgcqhkjOPQEBAiB/////////////////////////////////////////7TBEBCAqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqYSRShRAQge0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0JgtenHcQyGQEQQQqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq0kWiCuGaG4oIa04B7dLHdI0UySPU1+bXxhsinpxaJ+ztPZAiAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFN753qL3nNZYEmMaXPXT7QIBCANCAARuesOo7QMm9k+qILijTeh7yz0HU9DJrPIAnqVudaaG6w0/1n1ySnxa+X0bjWpUvmJA0IIKHO8baWBXp9BC4mMW-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me for the same?

Comment: What is failing? By failing, do you mean an error is thrown? Or do you mean result not matching some expected value? Or do you mean compilation error? Your question is not clear…

Comment: what is failing here? You got any success or the still facing issues? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @satyaa-akana did you find a solution? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: No solution @RahulGupta